# buddypress - manually activate new users account

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm learning about buddypress, I need it to add some community functions to a wordpress installation. I'm relatively new to buddypress but I have a bit of experience with wordpress. I'm looking for a way to manually approve new users registration. If user A sign up for the site, I want give the ability to a moderator to approve the account and send the activation email. Is there any filter or action that can achive this? I need to interact with the `WP_User` class or with buddypress api?

I've tested this filter but it will disable the activation and I need to disable the autoapproval of accounts to switch to manual account activation.

```
add_filter( 'bp_registration_needs_activation', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the plugin BuddyPress Registration Options?

Comment: No, not searched for plugins at the moment. I was looking for a programmatic way. Since I want to show some fields only if the user select a particular account type, I was looking at user api of wordpress to be able to setup custom accounts with capabilities